# Expression as var

Tags: functions, variables

Is it possible for a variable to be set to an expression that will be evaluated each time that variable is accessed? The idea would be that a user could then set the variable to be either a string or a function that returns a string. Perhaps something like this.

```
(setq test-variable (lambda () (if (string= (buffer-name) "*scratch*") "true" "false")))
(message "%s" test-variable) ;; prints true if in scratch buffer else print false
```

It would even be great if there were a way to evaluate something in the same way that the `global-mode-line` variable gets evaluated

```
(setq test-variable '(:eval (if (string= (buffer-name) "*scratch*") "true" "false")))
(message "%s" test-variable) ;; prints true if in scratch buffer else print false
```

It would also be work if all it took was some simple wrapper

```
(setq test-variable '(:eval (if (string= (buffer-name) "*scratch*") "true" "false")))
(message "%s" (test-wrapper test-variable)) ;; prints true if in scratch buffer else print false
```

Thank you,

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a function: `(fset 'test-variable (lambda () (if (string= (buffer-name) "*scratch*") "true" "false")))
(message "%s" (test-variable))`.

Comment: Emacs lisp does not have global symbol macros, unlike [common lisp](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_1.htm).

Comment: The function solution should work, although it would be nice to have a bit more sugar to it, like [Scheme parameters](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-39/srfi-39.html).

Comment: @sds That sounds like what I would want

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is a function rather than a variable -- evaluating something every time it's accessed is exactly what a function is for.

You can pass around the symbol for a function, and then apply it later, which I think gets at using it like a variable too.

Does this do what you're asking?

```
(defun is-scratch ()
  (string= (buffer-name) "*scratch*"))

(setq message-generator 'is-scratch)

(message "%s" (apply message-generator nil))
```

Comment: If you don't have a variable number of args, you can use `funcall`, i.e. `(funcall message-generator)`.

Comment: The issue is that in somebody else's code they have a variable that I believe would make much more sense as a function that returns the variable. I cannot change their code to take a function instead because that would possibly work other peoples workflows. So I was hoping there would be some elegant solution such as the one available in the modeline.